# Why Cucumber JVM does not fail step or step definition when an exception is thrown?

Tags: junit, cucumber-jvm

I am writing cucumber jvm test code using junit as runner. Some how i notice that even though the test code is throwing a lot of runtime exceptions. The step/step definitions still show as 'PASSED' in report.

If i remembered correctly, i've use cucumber jvm before and it always fail the steps whenever there is an exception. But now, i can only fail the step when assertion fail.

What am i missing here? Could anyone give an advice/hint?

Comment: Can you please elaborate with your step definition code? If a step fails, then no further steps are executed further, only that particular step will be marked as failed and other steps as skipped. Are you expecting all steps from failed steps to be shown as failed in your report?

Comment: @Bhuvanesh Mani thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using try catch statements? if so then you see the catch block logs.
If you want to let the scenario fail then use how possible more asserts and Boolean functions.
Can't help you out with the info you shared.